# PHP Ajax I want to make a change permanent

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have an "Add as Buddy" button and I want it to change permanently to "Pending Request" until the request is confirmed when I click it. When I click the button, yes it changes to "Pending Request" but whenever I refresh the page, it reverts back to "Add as Buddy". Any help on how I should do it?

PHP PART

```
<div class="member" data-user="<?php echo $member['xmpp_user']; ?>" data-uid="<?php echo $member['uid']; ?>">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/wheewhew/user/<?php echo $member['uid']; ?>/photos/<?php echo $member['profile_pic']; ?>" />
    <div class="member_name"><?php echo $member['firstname']." ".$member['lastname']; ?></div>
    <div id="addbutton"><button type="submit" class="add" id="<?php echo $member['uid']; ?>"> Add as Buddy </button></div>
</div>
```

JS PART

```
function addBuddy(){
    var xmpp_user = $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-user')+'@example.com/default';
    var to_uid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-uid');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./ajax/addBuddy",
        data: "from_uid="+uid+"&to_uid="+to_uid,

       success: function(data) {
          var ret = eval('('+data+')');
          if(ret.status == 'success'){
            connection.send($pres({to:xmpp_user,type:'subscribe'}).tree());
          }
          else if(ret.status == 'requested'){
            document.getElementById(to_uid).innerHTML="Pending Request";
          }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: on page load check the status from db and print

Comment: how do i do that? I dont have any idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store that this user has an invitation somewhere, typically this is done in a database, after you stored you can do something like this

```
<div id="addbutton">
<button type="submit" class="add" id="<?php echo $member['uid']; ?>"> 
<?php echo $has_request? "Pending Request":"Add as Buddy"?> 
</button></div>
```

Comment: Assuming you already have a connection to the database you would use a query like `SELECT id, invited_id FROM user_invitations WHERE id = :user_id AND invited_id = :user_page_id` (keep in mind this is just an example) and then see if it returns a record, in case it does you would set $has_request.

Comment: If you're saying you have no idea how to connect PHP to a database at all, google it. There are plenty of simple tutorials; [here's one](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp).

Comment: (And yes, I realized when I saw the reference to Friendster that that particular one is a bit out-of-date. But it's still a good starting point, and it's updated enough to use mysqli.)

Answer (score 0):

That's because, in your PHP code, you're not checking if there is a request pending. You could also wonder if that is a thing you should be doing.

Think about how you want the UX to work and if it makes sense.

Comment: How do I check in PHP if it is pending? I really need help about this matter. I'm a newbie in web developments.

Comment: You don't typically do that. Requests complete in a matter of seconds, it's highly dynamic. If you want an interactive website use more JavaScript than PHP.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - I don't think they mean request as in an HTTP request. I think he's referring to the Add as Buddy request the OP mentioned. My guess is, this is like FB or IM, where if you add a person to your chat list, their name continues to say "Pending" until they respond, regardless if it's within the same session or not.